# Why I am not able to populate the json data in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Booststrap` table to populate `json` data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <title>
  Boostrap Modal Example
 </title>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">

var data = 
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test0",
        "price": "$0"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": "$1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "price": "$2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3",
        "price": "$3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "test4",
        "price": "$4"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "test5",
        "price": "$5"
    }
  
];
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   alert("I am ready");
   $('#modalTable').on('shown',function()
   {

    console.log("I am in bro");

   $('#mytable').bootstrapTable({

                data: data

   });

   });
  });

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTable">Show Table</button>



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalTable" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   <table id="mytable" data-toggle="table" class="table">
        
    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="id">Id</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="name"> Name</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="price">Price</th>
                          
                        </tr>
                    </thead>



   </table>

  </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



 </body>
</html>
```

I tried this also, but it dint work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert("I am ready");
    $('#modalTable').on('shown', function () {

        console.log("I am in bro");

        $('#mytable').bootstrapTable({

            columns: [{
                field: 'id',
                title: 'Id'
            }, {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Name'
            }, {
                field: 'price',
                title: 'Price'
            }

            ],

            data: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Item 1',
                price: '$1'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Item 2',
                price: '$2'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Item 2',
                price: '$2'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Item 2',
                price: '$2'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Item 2',
                price: '$2'
            }]

        });

    });
});
```

**This is the out put I am getting**
after clicking on the button modal popup pops up. but without data,
[image]

But it would be better If i can do it in first way.

I dont know where I am lacking. When I dont use modal. table works fine but as I include modal. it doesnt work. 
Please help

Comment: A lot of the examples I found actually import a JSON file instead of referencing an array. I think its possible that the issue here is that your data is not actually JSON. 

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#table-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u6xv7zve/2/)**

The problem was with 3 things:

> - I don't see the `link` to <kbd>**[`bootstraptable.css`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.0/bootstrap-table.min.css)**</kbd> and **<kbd>[`bootstraptable.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.0/bootstrap-table.min.js)</kbd>** in your `html`.
> - `Bootstrap Modal event` on open should be `shown.bs.modal` instead of just `shown`. So it would be
>     `$('#modalTable').on('shown.bs.modal',function()` instead of
>     `$('#modalTable').on('shown',function()`
> - Remove `data-toggle` from your `table`. It is not required there.

So below is the updated `JS` and `HTML`

**`JS`**

```
$('#modalTable').on('shown.bs.modal',function()
{
    console.log("I am in bro");
    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
    });
});
```

**`HTML`**

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="id">Id</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="name"> Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="price">Price</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: One thing I want to know... bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css are main file. if we include this do we really need to include others , as you mentioned. Then what is the difference between them.

Comment: Yes @varun .. the table you are using is a plugin which co-ordinates with `bootstrap`. `Bootstrap` is a framework which is for responsive design and `bootstraptable` is a plugin built upon it.. :)